# Don't know why: free(): invalid next size (fast):

Tags: c

I made a function to test function my_memmove() and I get error at free() function.
free(): invalid next size (fast):
If I comment out the free function the program run ok, but wouldn't I have memory leeks.
Sorry for the long code, but I'm lost.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DATA_SET_SIZE_W (10)
#define MEM_SET_SIZE_B  (32)
#define MEM_SET_SIZE_W  (8)
#define MEM_ZERO_LENGTH (16)

#define TEST_MEMMOVE_LENGTH (16)
 void print_array(unsigned char arr[], unsigned int n){
        int i;
        for (i=0;i<n;i++)
            printf("%d ", arr[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
int32_t * reserve_words(size_t length){
    int32_t *buf;
    buf = malloc (sizeof(uint8_t)*length);
    if( buf == NULL ){ 
        printf( "Fatal Error: Failed to malloc memory" );
        return buf; 
    }
    return buf;
}
uint8_t * my_memmove(uint8_t * src, uint8_t * dst, size_t length){
    int i;
//Check if overlap of source and destination
    if ((src+length-1)>dst)
        return 0; 

// Copy data from scr[] to dst[] 
    for (i=0; i<length; i++){ 
        *(dst+i) = *(src+i);
        *(src+i)=0; 
    }
    return dst; 
} 
// Driver program to test above functions 
int main(void) {
    uint8_t i;
    uint8_t * set;
    uint8_t * ptra;
    uint8_t * ptrb;

    printf("test_memmove1() - NO OVERLAP\n");
    set = (uint8_t*) reserve_words( MEM_SET_SIZE_W );

  if (! set ) 
  {
    printf ("TEST_ERROR_1 \n");
  }
  
  ptra = &set[0];
  ptrb = &set[16];
  
  /* Initialize the set to test values */
  for( i = 0; i < MEM_SET_SIZE_B; i++)
  {
    set[i] = i;
  }

  print_array(set, MEM_SET_SIZE_B);
  my_memmove(ptra, ptrb, TEST_MEMMOVE_LENGTH);
  print_array(set, MEM_SET_SIZE_B);

  for (i = 0; i < TEST_MEMMOVE_LENGTH; i++)
  {
    if (set[i + 16] != i)
    {
      printf ("TEST_ERROR_2 \n");
    }
  }

  free(set );
  printf ("TEST_OK \n");

  return 0;
}
```

I do not know what to do.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ` buf = malloc (sizeof(uint8_t)*length);` Isn't the sizeof wrong?

Comment: `*(dst+i) = *(src+i);` is better written as `dst[i] = src[i]`...

Comment: Don't use casts.  Using the correct types at all places in your program would have shown you your errors.

Comment: @Stephan: Get a habit of passing the actual variable to the `sizeof` and remove the redundant cast, i.e. `int32_t *buf = malloc(sizeof *buf * length);`. It prevents errors of this kind and removes unnecessary duplication. Also, you are mixing `size_t`, `unsigned int` and `int` for your array length and indexing, which is usually a bad idea because signed and unsigned comparisons might not work the way you expect.

Comment: @KamilCuk It worked with uint32_t. buf = malloc (sizeof(uint32_t)*length). But I do not know why :(

Answer (score 3):

Maybe there is not even an error in your functional code, but you are testing with the wrong values.

```
set = (uint8_t*) reserve_words( MEM_SET_SIZE_W );
```

You have now allocated 8 *bytes* (not *words*).

```
ptrb = &set[16];
```

There is no such element. The highest is `set[7]`.

```
my_memmove(ptra, ptrb, TEST_MEMMOVE_LENGTH);
```

You are moving 16 bytes from the allocated 8 bytes to an area that is not yours. Probably this is where you corrupt the heap.

Any other errors in your code I leave to you.